# Passing back redirect url parameters to main window after successful Paypal login in popup window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have to implement a "Connect with Paypal" feature in a React SPA application.

The login is implemented by using the Paypal provided code

```
paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
        login.render ({
            "appid": MYAPPID,
            "authend": "sandbox",
            "scopes": <SCOPES>,
            "containerid": "paypalButton",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "returnurl": <RETURN_URL>
        });
    });
```

This opens a new popup window, which happens completely out of my control. The popup opens the Paypal login form, which after successful login, redirects to the `<RETURN_URL>`.

All this happens in the popup window. Since this is a SPA, I don't want to refresh the page.

What I need is a way to close the redirected popup, while also preserving the URL params that were passed back to it from Paypal, and have that information (the URL params) transferred to the main app window.

Is this possible and if so how? The Paypal documentation is pretty outdated from what I can tell.

Comment: Have you considered something like the [broadcast channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)? If `<RETURN_URL>` has the same origin as your SPA, could you set up a channel listener in your SPA, have your `<RETURN_URL>` page post a message back to your SPA containing `window.location.search` for the queryparams, and then close itself on successful transmission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to share this data. I am assuming *your `{RETURN_URL}` and SPA are on the same origin.* Here are two approaches I came up with to communicate between your SPA and the pop-up.

1) Use the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) if the API is supported on browsers and versions you require [(caniuse)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel). No Safari, and limited Edge! Polyfills also exist.

Here's some sample code you can use to try out the different approaches. Two pages (one's your SPA, the other one's the RETURN_URL you give for PayPal to send you to on completion).

Your SPA `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My SPA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const bc = new BroadcastChannel("my_spa_listener");
      window.open("./newpage.html?some=true&query=hi&params=cat", "_new");
      bc.onmessage = function(ev) {
        console.log("Got a message from the pop-up: ", ev.data);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the pop-up `newpage.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PayPal redirected me here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
        const bc = new BroadcastChannel("my_spa_listener");
        bc.postMessage(window.location.search);
        bc.close();
        window.close();
      }, 2500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2) Good old [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You [can use it](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) pretty much anywhere!

`index.html`:

```
const targetKey = "popup-queryparams";
window.addEventListener("storage", function(ev) {
    if (ev.key === targetKey) {
        console.log("Got the data: ", ev.newValue);
        // clear key in case it conatins sensitive info
        localStorage.removeItem(targetKey);
    }
});
window.open("./newpage.html?some=true&query=hi&params=cat", "_new");
```

Then in the pop-up, before you close the window, just do:

`localStorage.setItem("popup-queryparams", window.location.search);`

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the Broadcast API at all, and I didn't know that storage modifications emit a `storage` event. I feel a better person.